# CSS grid height wrong when using percent as grid gap

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I'm using a CSS grid with images in it and wanted to set a gap between elements that scales with the size of the grid. So I set the `grid-gap` to 2%, but doing that caused the grid height to be wrong, and caused the grid contents to overlap with the next element below. Using other units as the `grid-gap`, like vw works fine.

If I want to use a percentage as the gap, how can I fix the overlap problem?

Here's a minimal reproduction of the issue I'm running into:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, auto);
  grid-gap: 10%;
  background-color: #EEE
}

.grid-item {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP839r6HwAHngMKGIKGywAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" class="grid-item">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP839r6HwAHngMKGIKGywAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" class="grid-item">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP839r6HwAHngMKGIKGywAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" class="grid-item">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP839r6HwAHngMKGIKGywAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" class="grid-item">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP839r6HwAHngMKGIKGywAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" class="grid-item">
</div>
<p>Why does this line overlap with the grid?</p>
```

Comment: I think the issue of percentage-based grid-row gaps is still being settled. You may want to use another unit of length in the meantime. https://blogs.igalia.com/mrego/2018/08/10/changes-on-css-grid-layout-in-percentages-and-indefinite-height/

Comment: use grid-gap:10vw; instead

Comment: @CarolMcKay that works OK, and it's what I'm doing as a fall back, but it's still not quite ideal as the element has something like `width: 90%; max-width: 500px`, so that both a constant gap and a viewport relative gap work for some cases but are a little off for others.

Comment: personally in this case I would ditch grid for flex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 10% seems to be honoured with flex.

```css
.container {
   width:90%;
   margin:0 auto;
   display:block;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  width:100%;
  background-color: #EEE
}

.grid-item {
  flex:0 0 45%;
  max-width:500px;
  margin:0 0 10% 0;
  display: block;
}

img.grid-item:last-of-type {
   margin-bottom:0;
}
```

```html
 <div class="container">
<div class="grid">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP839r6HwAHngMKGIKGywAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" class="grid-item">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP839r6HwAHngMKGIKGywAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" class="grid-item">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP839r6HwAHngMKGIKGywAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" class="grid-item">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP839r6HwAHngMKGIKGywAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" class="grid-item">
  <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAYAAAAfFcSJAAAADUlEQVR42mP839r6HwAHngMKGIKGywAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==" class="grid-item">
</div>
<p>Why does this line overlap with the grid?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice, this looks pretty close. Last thing to figure out is making each element have the right aspect ratio, instead of their original height

Comment: Ah cool, wrapping each img in an extra div fixed that issue. Then yeah, just tweaking the percent will let me set the number of columns well enough!